# Finding the nth term of a given summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

In the summation $$\sum_{r=1}^n    u_r = n^2(2n+3)$$ I am asked to find $u_r$. I tried using $S_n -S_{n-1}$ as follow: $$u_n=S_n -S_{n-1}=n^2(2n+3)-(n-1)^2(2(n-1)+3)$$ to get my final answer as $6n^2-1$. However, when checking my solution on Wolfram Alpha by trying to sum $6n^2-1$ from $r=1$ to $n$, the software gives me $6n^3 -n$. What’s wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You have to sum up $6r^2-1$ from $r=1$ to $n$. If you sum up $6n^2-1$ you get $n$ times the same term, i.e.
$$\sum_{r=1}^n6n^2-1=n\cdot (6n^2-1)=6n^3-n$$
instead of
$$\sum_{r=1}^n6r^2-1=n^2 (2 n+3)$$

Comment: Hello :) Your $u_r$ is $6r^2-1$. You haven't done anything wrong. Your only mistake is summing up $6n^2-1$, which is constant for every $r$ instead of $6r^2-1$.

Comment: Thanks!!I used 6r^2-1 on wolfram alpha and got the right thing.

Comment: You're welcome :D